# Streaming oxygene saturation data from apple watch

Tags: streaming, apple-watch, healthkit, oxygene

I am currently developing an application in order to stream data like heart rate, active energy burned, distance walking and oxygen saturation from the Apple Watch.

For this, I have followed all the steps to build a workout session and checked all the authorization required.

All the data streaming are working but not the oxygen saturation.

The last one is not working because this data are never collected.

In the configuration workout, I have tried different things like change the activity Type or the location type, but I never get the oxygen saturation data.

Currently, I can get the oxygen saturation data with the app of the Watch but is it possible to get this data in other way like the heart rate ?
Do I need to put some special configuration for my workout ?

Regards,

Lucas

Comment: did you find any solution ?